# SCALA: Error while downloading blobs from an endpoint: Unexpected character '<' at input index 0

Tags: scala, download, blob, databricks

I'm using **Databricks**, writing code with **Scala**. I download blob files from an endpoint of an API, to which I do not have access otherwise. Sometimes I might get an html response, which should be handled in my code, but I cannot figure out, how.

Download function:

```
def dl: (String => String) = { fileUrl: String => {
      val token = getToken();
          val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http(fileUrl)
          .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
          .asString;
      try {
        retry(4){

          if (response.code != 200) {
            throw new javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException(response.code)
          }
                  response.body;
        }
      } catch {
        case e: javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException => {
          println("error HTTPException " + e + fileUrl);
          "failed";
        }
      }
    }}
```

In this function, if successful, I return the **response.body**, which in normal situations is an xml file, but sometimes I get this error, which is why I thought it might be an html response from the endpoint:

```
spray.json.JsonParser$ParsingException: Unexpected character '<' at input index 0 (line 1, position 1), expected JSON Value: <html>?
```

Additionally, the response.body will be written to a JSON file, but the error actually comes from the download function.

Could you help me, how to handle this situation?

Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: Which library you use for fetching data? Exception suggest Spray but with Spray request looks differently. Knowing this might help figuring out why code is parsed as JSON at all.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The library is spray yes, but I also have these ones: org.apache.spark.sql.functions.get_json_object, DefaultJsonProtocol._. Additionally, I tried scala.util.parsing.json._ to JSON.parsefull(), but there I have this type mismatch error, because it expects string, but gets Option[Any]. Could it occur when I write it out as JSON? Even though this looks like it's coming from the download?

Comment: If you are in control of printing the error you can run `exception.printStackTrace()` to see whole call stack - this way you should know where was the last line of code that you controlled (instead of e.g. library) and take a look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments, it actually helped me a lot. The error was coming from the function, where I generate a token. This function is called from the **download function** above, and it returns the token after parsing it as JSON. Sometimes there were time out errors, or an unhandled exception, that I stated above.

So I call the **token-generator function** (*getToken()*) outside of the **download function** (*dl()*), so instead of generate and parse a new one every time we call the download function, it is generated once, and then use the same token to download an amount of files.

```
    val token = getToken();

    def dl: (String => String) = { fileUrl: String => {
          val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http(fileUrl)
          .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
          .asString;
      try {
        retry(4){

          if (response.code != 200) {
            throw new javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException(response.code)
          }
                  response.body;
        }
      } catch {
        case e: javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException => {
          println("error HTTPException " + e + fileUrl);
          "failed" + e;
        }
      }
    }}
```

Another trick, which I will use more often to improve the performance: **Handle more exceptions!** Spark Scala is able to handle exceptions by itself, but it sometimes improves the performance, if you handle it manually. For example, in my case, next to the HTTPException, I added a JSON parser exception, because scala couldn't handle it.

```
case e: spray.json.JsonParser$ParsingException => {
          println("error JsonParser exception " + e );
          "failed" + e;
        }
```

By these modifications I improved the runtime! Before, it was running for 1.5 hours with 100.000 files. After these changes it takes 15-20 minutes!!